# cpu temperature influenced by integrated graphic card?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, cooling, temperature

I have an intel skylake i5 6600 no oc..still no dedicated graphic card..here it's summer,ambient temperature can get up to 30° and during games sessions my cpu temp can get to 80-85° with stock cooler..this scares me a bit,and i'm wondering:if i will have a dedicated card,will my cpu be cooler because it's inbuilt graphic card won't be under stress ?
thanks for answers,and pardon my not great english :D

Comment: That seems pretty high, but I've managed to get a 6600 to about that while running Prime95 in a closed-in case (Silencio 352). It was mainly an airflow/cooling issue, so I guess check that your cooler is firmly attached, clear of dust, and whether the case has appropriate airflow as a first step.

Comment: Hard to give a definitive answer, it's very much a depends. Depends on the card's efficiency for a start, AMD cards tend to push out more heat than an Nvidia of similar performance. Also a big depends would be if you were going to keep the same graphics settings as you use for on-board, or would up your visuals and thus demands once you got a discrete graphics card.

Comment: Of course it would be cooler. The question should rather be: How much? If you're sure you have enough general ventilation inside the case and the CPU cooler is properly mounted, and it's still not enough: Get a better cooling option.

Comment: well,using prime95 the temperature grows very fast,and I didn't want to go further so I stopped it when it reached 75°,anyway,once I've stopped it,cpu immediatly started to get cool to 30°,but still i'm going to check the cooler,thanks for the answers,I'll keep you updated

Comment: well! I managed to fix my temperature by reinstalling again the cooler.And It worked.My bad that i thought that some movement of the cooler was normal.Thank you very much for the solution.Now it takes very long time to grow up of temp.Thanks

Comment: If you solved the question you can answer it yourself. Make sure to accept that answer, too. There may be a cooldown period before you can do so.